# 'SAP Android Apps' Not able to create Project - "Template Generation Wizard Error"

Tags: android, templates, mobile, eclipse-plugin, sap-basis

I am trying to follow the below article to integrate SAP module with Android mobile:
https://blogs.sap.com/2012/07/18/developing-an-android-app-consuming-data-from-sap-is-just-a-few-clicks-away/

I have followed each and every step as suggested. Now I am able to create a project using "Proxy Generation".

But not able to create a new project with "Starter Application Project" wizard. Getting error as shown in below image

[image]

I am trying to create TestFlight sample application with provided sample credentials.
This error seems to be from Eclipse or System generation error.

On other system it is working fine.

My system setup :
Windows 7
JDK path set to 1.7
ADT 22

Can anybody please help me for this issue.?

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that proxy generation does work, there seems to be a problem in generation of the application classes. We'll need a bit more info, such as the OData service used and complete stacktrace (not so visible from the screenshot...). However, I strongly recommend you to use the new version of the toolkit for Andrdoid in Gateway Productivity Accelerator (more info in this blog: http://scn.sap.com/community/netweaver-gateway/blog/2013/05/10/new-gateway-tool--sap-netweaver-gateway-productivity-accelerator). This issue should be resolved there.

Best Regards,
Gal